# If $W$ is a subspace of $V$, prove that there exists a basis of $V$ given a basis of $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that the dimension of $V$ is equal to $n$. If $W$ has a basis $(w_1,...,w_k)$ and $W$ is a subspace of $V$, prove that there exists $b_1,...,b_{n-k}\in V-W$ such that $(w_1,...,w_k,b_1,...,b_{n-k})$ is a basis of $V$. Also, show that every subspace $W\subseteq V$ has a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ so that the kernel of $T$ is $W$.

The first question seems pretty straightforward. We just choose $b_1,...b_{n-k}$ to be linearly independent from $w_1,...,w_k$ (and we know this is possible because $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and the dimension of $V$ is $n$). So we would end up with $w_1,...,w_k,b_1,...b_{n-k}$ or $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$. Since $\dim(V)=n$, we know that $n$ linearly independent vectors also span $V$, so $B =(w_1,...,w_k,b_1,...b_{n-k})$ is a basis of $V$.

For the second question, we want the kernel of $T$ to be all of $w_1,...,w_k$, since we know these span $W$. I don't know how to construct the transformation, though. It seems like constructing transformations is where I struggle.

Comment: Recall that the endomorphism $T$ is uniquely determined by its values on any basis. So for example you simply need to send $w_1, \dots, w_k$ to $0$ and $b_1, dots, b_{n-k}$ to themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first prove a lemma.

**Lemma.** If $\{u_1,\dots,u_r\}$ is a basis for the subspace $U$ of $V$ and $U\ne V$, then there exists a vector $v\in V$ such that $\{u_1,\dots,u_r,v\}$ is linearly independent.

*Proof.* Let $v\in V$, $v\notin U$, which exists by hypothesis. Suppose
$$
\alpha_1u_1+\dots+\alpha_ru_r+\beta v=0.
$$
If $\beta\ne0$, then
$$
v=-\beta^{-1}(\alpha_1u_1+\dots+\alpha_ru_r)\in U
$$
contrary to the hypothesis. Then $\beta=0$ and so
$$
\alpha_1u_1+\dots+\alpha_ru_r=0.
$$
Since the set $\{u_1,\dots,u_r\}$ is linearly independent, we get $\alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_r=0$. Therefore $\{u_1,\dots,u_r,v\}$ is linearly independent. QED

Now suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. Since $W\ne V$ by hypothesis, we can find $v_1\in V$, $v_1\notin W$. Consider $W_1=\langle w_1,\dots,w_k,v_1\rangle$. If $W_1\ne V$, we can reapply the lemma obtaining $v_2$ and $W_2$ in the same fashion. The procedure can be repeated, but it must stop because no set with more than $n$ elements is linearly independent. Thus we stop at $W_{n-k}=V$.

For the second part, define $T\colon V\to V$ by
$$
\begin{cases}
T(w_i)=0 & i=1,2,\dots,k\\
T(v_j)=v_j & j=1,\dots,n-k
\end{cases}
$$
and show that $\ker T=W$.